# Test Alexa Skill on local Echo

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I created a Alexa Skill with an AWS Lambda. I want to have this Skill only on my personal echo Without certificating or even publishing it. Is this possile? Didnt find a way

Answer (score 0):

Just don't submit it for publishing. As long as the skill is not published it will only be available in the developer account and for the beta testers, if at all you have added any. Then setup your echo with that developer account.